# Special Characters Make My Program Crash?

Tags: java, oop, variables

In my program, I have 2 modes. One for quiz insertion and the other for quiz solution. Whenever I use a special character or even a space within my string input (ShortAnswerQuestion or FillInTheBlank), I get a run-time error or my program goes 2 or 3 steps into the future. No spaces/ special characters, works perfectly fine.  Any way I can fix this? Here's my main:

public class QuizApplication {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n,m,l;
    System.out.println("This is the insertion mode\n");
    System.out.println("How many short-answer questions would you like to include in your quiz?");
    n=s.nextInt();
    ShortAnswerQuestion[] qu0= new ShortAnswerQuestion[n];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        System.out.println("Please insert question "+(i+1)+": ");
        String Q0=s.next();
        System.out.println("Please insert the correct answer: ");
        String A0=s.next();
        qu0[i]=new ShortAnswerQuestion(Q0,A0);


    }
    System.out.println("How many fillin the blank questions would you like to include in your quiz?");
    m=s.nextInt();
    FillInBlankQuestion[] qu1= new FillInBlankQuestion[m];
    int o;
    for(o=0;o<m;o++){
        System.out.println("Please insert question "+(o+1)+": ");
        String Q1=s.next();
        System.out.println("Please insert the correct answer: ");
        String A1=s.next();
        qu1[o]=new FillInBlankQuestion(Q1,A1);
    }
    System.out.println("How many true or false questions would you like to include in your quiz?");
    l=s.nextInt();
    TrueFalseQuestion[] qu2= new TrueFalseQuestion[l];
    int x;
    for(x=0;x<l;x++){
        System.out.println("Please insert question "+(x+1)+": ");
        String Q2=s.next();
        System.out.println("Please insert the correct answer: ");
        boolean A2=s.nextBoolean();
        qu2[x]=new TrueFalseQuestion(Q2,A2);


}
    System.out.println("Moving to Quiz Mode\n");
    System.out.println("Short-answer questions:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        System.out.println("Question "+(i+1)+" \n"+qu0[i].getMyText());

        System.out.println(qu0[i].CheckAnswer(qu0[i].GetAnswer()));
            } 
    System.out.println("\nFill-in the blank questions:\n");
    for(o=0;o<m;o++){
        System.out.println("Question "+(o+1)+" \n"+qu1[o].getMyText());

        System.out.println(qu1[o].CheckAnswer(qu1[o].GetAnswer()));
            }
    System.out.println("\nTrue or False questions:\n");
    for(x=0;x<l;x++){
        System.out.println("Question "+(x+1)+" \n"+qu2[x].getMyText());

        System.out.println(qu2[x].CheckAnswer(qu2[x].GetAnswer()));
            }
    System.out.println("END OF QUIZ");
```

}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `s.next()`, which reads a single word, where you should be using `s.nextLine()`, which reads an entire line.

To fix this, you'll need to change every

```
s.next()
```

to

```
s.nextLine()
```

But you'll also need to add an extra `s.nextLine()` after your calls to `s.nextInt()` and `s.nextBoolean()`.  The reason is that `s.nextInt()` and `s.nextBoolean()` don't read in the end-of-line character that follows the value that they read.  So where you wrote

```
l=s.nextInt();
```

you'll actually want

```
l=s.nextInt();
s.nextLine();
```

Lastly, using single-letter variable names is a really bad idea.  It makes your code much more difficult to read and understand.  It's best to use variable names that state what each variable is for.